# How can I pass multiple JSON list items to HttpPost?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api

I have implemented an API in C# .NET Web API

Have an employee class -

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WebPersonCacheAPI.Model
{
    public class Employee
    {


        public string EmployeeID { get; set; }

        public string Surname { get; set; }

        public string WindowsID { get; set; }

        public string Forenames { get; set; }

        public string PracticeCode { get; set; }

        public string SMTPAddress { get; set; }

        public string LineManager { get; set; }

        public string PracticeAdmin { get; set; }

        public string LeaveDate { get; set; }

        public string JobTitle { get; set; }

        public string HireDate { get; set; }

        public string Grade { get; set; }

        public decimal? RequiredHours { get; set; }

        public string BusinessTelephone { get; set; }

        public string MobileNumber { get; set; }

        public string ExtensionNumber { get; set; }

        public string DepartmentName { get; set; }

        public string Country { get; set; }

        public string DistinctName { get; set; }

        public string GradeDesc { get; set; }

        public string OfficeName { get; set; }

        public string UnitName { get; set; }

        public string Rank { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And a controller which saves the posted record to a database table:

```
  // POST: api/Employees

    [HttpPost]
   
    public async Task<IActionResult> PostEmployee([FromBody] Employee employee)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        _context.Employees.Add( employee);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        
        return CreatedAtAction("GetEmployee", new { id = employee.EmployeeID }, employee);
        
    }
```

When I post a single JSON record with Postman all works fine:

```
{
         "EmployeeID" : "PAC282811",
         "Surname" : "Smith",
         "WindowsID" : "CAMIS2",
         "Forenames" : "Ian",
         "PracticeCode" : "GS001",
         "SMTPAddress" : "ian.smith@company.com",
         "LineManager" : "PAC233455",
         "PracticeAdmin" : "PAC455322", 
         "LeaveDate" : "20/12/2020",
         "JobTitle" : "Developer",
         "HireDate" : "01/01/2001",
         "Grade" : "AS(3)",
         "RequiredHours" : 37,
         "BusinessTelephone" : "01763456456",
         "MobileNumber" : "07777237276",
         "ExtensionNumber" : "34433",
         "DepartmentName" : "Group Systems",
         "Country" : "UK(1)",
         "DistinctName" : "Ian Smith",
         "GradeDesc" : "AS(3)",
         "OfficeName" : "London",
         "UnitName" : "Group Systems",
         "Rank" : "AS(3)"
}
```

However, I need to post multiple records so I tried an API call with this JSON code

```
[
    {
         "EmployeeID" : "PAC282811",
         "Surname" : "Smith",
         "WindowsID" : "CAMIS2",
         "Forenames" : "Ian",
         "PracticeCode" : "GS001",
         "SMTPAddress" : "ian.smith@company.com",
         "LineManager" : "PAC233455",
         "PracticeAdmin" : "PAC455322", 
         "LeaveDate" : "20/12/2020",
         "JobTitle" : "Developer",
         "HireDate" : "01/01/2001",
         "Grade" : "AS(3)",
         "RequiredHours" : 37,
         "BusinessTelephone" : "01763456456",
         "MobileNumber" : "07777237276",
         "ExtensionNumber" : "34433",
         "DepartmentName" : "Group Systems",
         "Country" : "UK(1)",
         "DistinctName" : "Ian Smith",
         "GradeDesc" : "AS(3)",
         "OfficeName" : "Cambridge",
         "UnitName" : "Group Systems",
         "Rank" : "AS(3)"
},

    {
         "EmployeeID" : "PAC12221",
         "Surname" : "Jones",
         "WindowsID" : "CAMDJ1",
         "Forenames" : "David",
         "PracticeCode" : "GS001",
         "SMTPAddress" : "david.jones@company.com",
         "LineManager" : "PAC233455",
         "PracticeAdmin" : "PAC455322", 
         "LeaveDate" : "18/01/2021",
         "JobTitle" : "Developer",
         "HireDate" : "01/01/2001",
         "Grade" : "AS(3)",
         "RequiredHours" : 37,
         "BusinessTelephone" : "01763456456",
         "MobileNumber" : "07777237276",
         "ExtensionNumber" : "34433",
         "DepartmentName" : "Group Systems",
         "Country" : "UK(1)",
         "DistinctName" : "David Jones",
         "GradeDesc" : "AS(3)",
         "OfficeName" : "Cambridge",
         "UnitName" : "Group Systems",
         "Rank" : "AS(3)"
}
]
```

I get the following error...

```
 "Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'WebPersonCacheAPI.Model.Employee' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {\"name\":\"value\"}) to deserialize correctly.\r\nTo fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {\"name\":\"value\"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List<T> that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.\r\nPath '', line 1, position 1."
```

Is my JSON list wrongly formed or do I need to change the controller code to handle multiple records?

Comment: You tried to pass an array to an action expecting a single item only. That's equivalent to passing an `Employee[]` array to a method expecting an `Employee`

Comment: Thanks so i need to build an array of Employee class to pass to?

Comment: You need a method that accepts an array of Employee.

Comment: try like List<Employee> as a parameter. Then use AddRange method to add as a list.